# Animating a Rotating Line

Tags: java, math, jpanel, awt, trigonometry

I am trying drawing a line with the function drawline from awt.Graphics package in my jpanel. I am also trying to  animate the line by rotating it by doing a full 360 degrees from its origin. I already got most of the part down expect the logic to rotate that line around.

Here is what the main code for the animation, i have a thread that call this function every 60 times per second:

```
public void Update(){
    degrees = ( ++degrees%360 == 0 ) ? 0 : degrees;
    angle = Math.toRadians(degrees);
    deltax = (Math.cos(angle) * deltax - Math.sin(angle) * deltay) + 100;
    deltay = (Math.sin(angle) * deltax + Math.cos(angle) * deltay) + 100;
}
```

I am adding an extra 100 because the changes seems to be very tiny.

After the values are updated, I call my frame to repaint the itself, with those update values.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics graph) 
{
    super.paintComponent(graph);
    //... other code here

    graph.drawLine(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, (int)deltax, (int) deltay);
}
```

It start fine but it quickly it starts showing some unexpected results.

Comment: What are the unexpected results?

Comment: It is kind of hard to explain but it rotates for a bit, then it stops after that it starts shrinking inward then somehow it look like there it draws to lines next to each other to finally restart at the 0,0 origin.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say for certain without seeing the actual results, but I strongly suspect it is coming out wrong because you're adding a fixed constant to the variables deltaX and deltaY.

You should instead multiply each of them by a fixed amount. Try

```
deltax = (Math.cos(angle) * deltax - Math.sin(angle) * deltay) * 100;
deltay = (Math.sin(angle) * deltax + Math.cos(angle) * deltay) * 100;
```

If that's not enough, increase the multiplier; if it's too much, reduce it.

Comment: I just tried it but now deltax and deltay values are 0, well it is giving me 0 and -0.